# need help in this ( mute picture box problem )

Tags: .net, vb.net

iam working in media player for my own every thing in code is working but if i pressed on mute picture box to mute sound and re-open another video or music file the sound is playing and the sign in mute picture box is show that iam in mute mode 
this is the code for mute picture box :

```
Private Sub Volume_PictureBox_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Volume_PictureBox.Click
    Try
        If MuteBol = False Then
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.mute = True
            MuteBol = True
            Volume_PictureBox.Image = My.Resources.Muted_Volume_Hover'mute picture
            MuteToolStripMenuItem.Checked = True
            Me.ToolTip1.SetToolTip(Volume_PictureBox, "UnMute")

        ElseIf MuteBol = True Then
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.mute = False
            MuteBol = False
            Volume_PictureBox.Image = My.Resources.Volume_Hover'un-mute picture 
            MuteToolStripMenuItem.Checked = False
            Me.ToolTip1.SetToolTip(Volume_PictureBox, "Mute")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message & ex.Source)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly is it that you're asking? When you open a new file while mute is active, do you want that new file to be muted? Or do you want it to be playing, but instead want the mute button to change its display back to inactive?

Comment: Just set mute = True again when the user opens another file.

Comment: erekalper :when i open new file i need to be muted not un-muted hope it's clear now

Comment: Hans how can i do it please !

Answer (score 0):

Not to answer for Hans, but if what you need is for newly opened songs to be muted if mute is already selected, it looks like you just need something simple, like:

```
If [a new song is opened or the current file changes or something like this]
    If MuteBol = True Then AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.mute = True
End If
```

Seems simple enough, unless this isn't what you're looking for. Hope this works!

Comment: it dos'nt work i try do this IF[axwindowmediaPlayer1.playstate=WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying ]then the rest of the code above but iT did'nt work!!!! i hope my if statment is true??

Comment: Can you copy and paste the actual code you have there? I noticed you wrote "windowmedia" instead of "windowsmedia". Unlikely, but that could be it. I'm not equipped to check if your If statement is true, but you easily are. Using the same If conditional, check some code that you know works, like a string output in a message box. If the message box pops up, you know your statement is true.

Comment: Also, if you paste more code, try not to do so in the comments section. You did well putting your code in the actual question and formatting it properly. To add more, just edit your question, make it clear that what you're adding is an edit, and add in the pertinent code/information. It would also be a good idea to leave a comment back here after you've done so, letting the people you're talking to know that you've edited the question (otherwise we'll likely never see it).